# history definition missing in ReactNode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I wrote a `Login` component which contains the hook `useEffect` that must access to the `history` object of the component:

```
export default (props: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const alertContext = useContext(AlertContext);
    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

    const { setAlert } = alertContext;
    const { login, error, clearErrors, isAuthenticated } = authContext;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            props.history.push('/');
        }

        if (error === 'Invalid Credentials') {
            setAlert(error, 'danger');
            clearErrors();
        }
        // es-lint-disable-next-line
    }, [error, isAuthenticated, props.history]);
```

even though I've defined `React.ReactNode` as `props` type for the component, I get:

> Property 'history' does not exist on type '{ children: ReactNode; }'

This error happen on this line:

```
props.history.push('/');
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your component which is functional component, you can use [`useHistory()`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) hook instead:

> React Router ships with a few hooks that let you access the state of the router and perform navigation from inside your components.

> The `useHistory` hook gives you access to the history instance that you may use to navigate.

You can import it as:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

So try as the following:

```
export default (props: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
   const history = useHistory()

   // rest of the code
}
```

Then use without `props` as:

```
history.push('/');
```

Comment: Thanks! So you confirm that there is no interface that includes history in Component?